# Mule:Difference between Anypoint studio and Mule studio IDE

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am new to Mule project development. Downloaded Anypoint studio and Mule studio. In Mule studio flow files are .mflow extension file whereas in anypoint it is just an xml configuration. Which one of these ide are used to develop Mule application and what is the difference in between these two. Exact purpose of two IDE's?

Answer (score 3):

Mule Studio which was called earlier is now turned into Anypoint Studio with some advanced feature .. Anypoint Studio which was earlier called as Mule studio now no longer support **.mflow** which was earlier supported in Mule Studio as the main Mule application configuration file.

Now Mule has depreciated **.mflow** in Anypoint studio and instead of .mflow, .xml files are considered as main config file ... you can get more information here :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Studio+with+3.5.0-M4+Runtime+Early+Access+Release+Notes

Both Ides are same and used for Mule application development and Anypoint Studio is the advanced version of Mule Studio with new features

Answer (score 1):

Mule Studio is an older version which is now called as Anypoint studio. Anypoint studio is very powerful IDE. The mflows in Mulestudio are now .xml format in anypoint studio and also endpoints are connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Mule Studio was older version and AnypointStudio is latest version
MuleStudio has different project structure 
AnypointStudio has different project structure.
MuleStudio supports .mflow but not AnypointStudio.
In anypoint studio muleflow are in src/main/app
In MuleStudio src/main/flows
Anypoint studio has advanced features

Answer (score 0):

The current documentation is based on Mule Studio. The screens are Mule Studio. The Endpoints are now Connectors.

Answer (score 0):

MuleStudio is also known as AnyPoint Studio and is used to design a 'flow', which is basically an integration having endpoints (inbound and outbound) and some pressing in-between. The Studio allows a visual or graphical view to design this flow. It supports round-tripping between the graphical and XML views. The Studio comes with an embedded runtime of the MuleESB.

The MuleESB is where the 'flow' designed in the Studio gets deployed. It is akin to an application server in concept. There are two versions available - a free, forum supported community edition and a paid for, SLA defined enterprise edition. The enterprise edition is a super set of the community edition in terms of features and capability.

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint Studio is an eclipse based IDE for development of flow etc

Anypoint Platform is a Mulesofts Enterprise integration platform which includes all tools and products build and manage integration applications and APIs such as Runtime Manager and API Designer for RAML which is a Web Based editor for RAML and Gateway etc

Anypoint Studio is one of the tools in Anypoint Platform that caters for the design and implementation part of the application and API lifecycle.